# Download all google sheet pages as JSON using link

Tags: java, android, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-export-url

I haven't been able to find a way to download all pages of a the sheet.

Right now I'm using this link to download the sheet as a txtfile (later I modify it easily to be compatible with JSON): https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/PAGELINK/gviz/tq

**This only downloads the first page of the sheet.** Is there a particular link where I can download the WHOLE sheet (all pages)?

I'm not using google-sheets-api.

EDIT:I am trying to download it through my android app. Sorry if I was not clear.

Comment: What did you tried? (see [ask])

Comment: What I have done so far is downloading through this https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/PAGELINK/gviz/tq link but this only downloads the first page of the sheet. So I had to make multiple sheets in order to download everything I wanted. Now I want o combine all the sheets to 1 and use pages instead. But I can't seem to find a way similar to the previous one where I download it through a link.

Comment: This looks like the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), you are *asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem*.  By the way, AFAIK, there is no a build-in "link" to download all the sheets in text format with a single link but you could create an app that does that.

Comment: I'm just asking if there is a way to download all the sheet pages as a txt file with a single link. There are surely other solutions and ways to do this. I thought that if there is a way to do this for the first page then there might be a way to do it for all the pages.

Answer (score 0):

At this time there is not a build-in single "link" to download all the sheets in text format but you could create an app that provides that. One alternative among others is to create web app by using Google Apps Script.